# My XAMPP server returns error when I try to connect mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

```
class poll
{
private $db;

public function __construct($dbConnection)
{
    $this->db = $dbConnection;
}

public function getPollData(){
    $sql = "SELECT poll_question, yes, no FROM poll WHERE poll_id=1";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $statement = execute();
    $pollData = $statement->fetchObject();
    return $pollData;
}
```

}

After I try to run this class in my code it says me

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function execute() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\poll\models\poll.php on line 21

I'm using xampp and can't undestand why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $statement->execute();

```
class poll

{

private $db;

public function __construct($dbConnection)
{
    $this->db = $dbConnection;
}

public function getPollData(){
    $sql = "SELECT poll_question, yes, no FROM poll WHERE poll_id=1";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $statement = $statement->execute(); // You miss the $statement var
    $pollData = $statement->fetchObject();
    return $pollData;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now there is another problem, my PHP Storm editor don't recognize "SELECT poll_question, yes, no FROM poll WHERE poll_id=1"; and prepare, execute, fetchObjects, are there any problem with library on my XAMPP??

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
$statement = execute();
```

To

```
 $statement = $statement->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you, but now there is another problem, my PHP Storm editor don't recognize "SELECT poll_question, yes, no FROM poll WHERE poll_id=1"; and prepare, execute, fetchObjects, are there any problem with library on my XAMPP??